# Brother MFC-J825DW network printer not detected on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

I have spent 4 days of over 20 hours trying to get my printer to recognize in 13.10. I have installed and un-installed both Ubuntu 13.10 and the printer numerous times. I have spent hours researching this. This is my last hope!

I can get the printer to install as a usb printer, but it is a network printer. The printer works fine on my windows 7 systems, but I want to use it with Ubuntu 13.10.

I have contacted Brother and was told that since Linux is so vast, they don't do much support (typical caned answer to get rid of someone). I have seen nothing pertaining to my particular problem.

Someone please HELP!
Thanks

Comment: The classical question then is, did you install these (latest) drivers (also the cups wrapper?). on this page: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006628_000&flang=4&type3=561 there is also a section about network connection.
printer drivers: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128

Comment: I did that many times jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned (initially) as a comment; make sure you installed the latest drivers (also the cups wrapper) from [this](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128) page. After you installed the Cups wrapper, you still have to set the parameters: open in your webbrowser:

```
http://localhost:631/printers
```

You will be asked for you (computer's) password. Click `Adimistration > Add Printer` and set following parameters.

for Device:

```
- "LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect"
```

for Device URI

```
- lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1
```

for Make/Manufacturer Selection

```
- Brother
```

for Model/Driver Selection

```
- Your printer's name
```

On the website of Brother, [Here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006628_000&flang=4&type3=561)  is the a section about network connection:

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I am awake enough. I did try just now but no luck.

Comment: Tried that after I woke up and IT WORKED!!

Comment: I tried that and IT WORKED!!!

Comment: I am glad it worked out.

Comment: Yes, tell me how

Answer (score 0):

Download the [CUPSwrapper driver](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj875dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006861_000&flang=4&type3=561) and the [LPR driver](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj875dw_us&os=128&dlid=dlf006859_000&flang=4&type3=559) from the Brother website and follow the directions provided on the resulting download page.

Comment: I did that too several times